# How show multiple cursors in the start of all lines?

Tags: multiple-cursors

Emacs 26.3

Suppose I has the  next text:

```
ACTION
ADVENTURE
COMEDY
CRIME
DRAMA
FANTASY
HISTORICAL
HISTORICAL
HORROR
MAGICAL
MYSTERY
PARANOID
PHILOSOPHICAL
POLITICAL
ROMANCE
SAGA
SATIRE
SCIENCE
SOCIAL
SPECULATIVE
THRILLER
URBAN
WESTERN
```

And I want by **Multiple cursors** https://github.com/magnars/multiple-cursors.el

add mulitple cursors in the start of all lines. I don't know count of all lines.

The result must be like this:
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The repository `README.md` -- https://github.com/magnars/multiple-cursors.el -- contains a basic usage introduction that states in relevant part:

- "*When you have an active region that spans multiple lines, the following will add a cursor to each line:*"

  `(global-set-key (kbd "C-S-c C-S-c") 'mc/edit-lines)`
- Mark many occurrences

  `mc/edit-lines`:  "*Adds one cursor to each line in the current region.*"

  `mc/edit-beginnings-of-lines`:  "*Adds a cursor at the start of each line in the current region.*"

  `mc/edit-ends-of-lines`:  "*Adds a cursor at the end of each line in the current region.*"